Samsung fridge freezing over
I have a Samsung fridge RS25J500DSR/AA that keeps freezing in the refrigerator side. There is no food anywhere in the fridge. It seems to track a temperature below freezing that I see with a logging thermometer. I replaced the fridge thermistor, nothing changed. Then replaced the main circuit board, again nothing.
When I measured the voltage on the connector it seems to match the temp in the service manual table, so it looks like the controller knows the fridge is below freezing. The freezer sensor also seems good.
I'm out of ideas. Any clues?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/H1DTj417SAMDeR1NA

Is your logging temperature sensor in the center of the middle shelf? If not, exactly where is it? What are the highest and lowest temperatures that you are recording over a typical day and how many times per day is the temperature reaching these extremes?

The thermometer is on the top shelf a few inches away from the thermistor. https://photos.app.goo.gl/6jjfZUxchhkZcWzY8  this is one screenshot. I also tried increasing the temperature offset by the maximum amount and for about a day the fridge stayed above freezing on the warmest setting https://photos.app.goo.gl/C2zy5uYoVkdZpxnCA

Please edit your question to prove the extra information.

If max temperature offset and warmest setting gives you a suitable temperature, which it appears that it does from your linked data, then suggest you just go with that.
You say there's no food in the fridge, so adding something with thermal mass while you work through this, such as a large number of water bottles, may help to stabilize and moderate the temperature swings. As always, keep easily frozen foods away from air vents.
Not sure if your temperature sensor is a thermistor, RTD or (unlikely) a thermocouple, but if this temperature range is not suitable, you can trick any of those to sense a different range by adding a resistor either in series or in parallel. You'd have to analyze the sensing circuit to know which and how high or low a resistance to add. This is a warranty-voiding hack, so if this refrigerator is new and still under warranty you might explore authorized service options first.

The max offset worked for about a day, and has not been above freezing since then. From the service manual I see that the sensors are thermistors and the all omh out correctly, and then I measure the voltage on the main board for each sensor, the value maps to the correct temperature (using the service manual). So, it appears that the main board knows what the actual temperature is in the fridge. I am trying to diagnose the fridge empty, but it was freezing over with food before. A service tech came years ago when it was under warranty when the freezer was too cold and said it was overstuffed.

@Toma So if you want to add a resistor to trick the controller into sensing a lower temperature and thereby raise the setpoint, the choice of series or parallel and the resistor value will depend on whether it's a PTC or NTC thermistor and its approximate resistance at the freezing point. Suggest you take what data you have to electronics.stackexchange for further guidance if needed, as I think this goes beyond the scope of DIY.stackexchange. Hope to see you there!

I understand how these thermistors work, the issue here is that the correct temperature is at the connector of the main circuit board. The voltage corresponds to the actual temperature in the fridge, so the main board knows the fridge is well below freezing but it continues to run the compressor.

@Toma And then it turns off the compressor when the fridge reaches a certain temperature below freezing, right? So let the controller think it's that temperature when it's actually above freezing and you're done. Unless the compressor is never turning off. But your graphs show that it is cycling and sensing temperature, so this is the hack to fix it.

It appears to me that it runs in open loop without any feedback. Almost as if it is in some sort of test mode and turns the compressor on and off based on time or something other than temperature. https://photos.app.goo.gl/H1DTj417SAMDeR1NA this is a more recent capture, with an "new" used main controller board from eday
